# C# SQLite - Is only updating 1 table out of 2

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I have a WPF application, so when people edit the details and click update I want it to update both tables at the same time. What seems to be happening is it’s only updating Tbl1 and both of them. This code worked fine for when I was inserting data into the tables. 
I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I don’t get any errors.

```
    private void ButtonEditTbl1Update_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var ModifiedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        {
            var ConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString;

            using (var DbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(ConnString))
            {
                try
                {
                    var insertIntoTable1String = (@"UPDATE [Tbl1]
                    SET Tbl1EnvironmentType = @Tbl1EnvironmentType, Tbl1URL = @Tbl1URL, Tbl1Server = @Tbl1Server, Tbl1ModifiedDate = @Tbl1ModifiedDate
                    WHERE(Tbl1.Tbl1Deleted = 0) AND (Tbl1.Tbl1ID = '" + Tbl1ID.Text + "')");
                    var insertIntoUsernamePasswordString = (@"UPDATE [Tbl2UsernamePassword]
                    SET Tbl2Username = @Tbl2Username, Tbl2Password = @Tbl2Password, Tbl1Server = @Tbl1Server, Tbl1ModifiedDate = @Tbl1ModifiedDate
                    WHERE(Tbl2UsernamePassword.Deleted = 0) AND (Tbl2UsernamePassword.Tbl2UsernamePasswordsID = '" + Tbl2UsernamePasswordsID.Text + "')");
                    var insertIntoTbl1Table = new SQLiteCommand(insertIntoTable1String);
                    var insertIntoTbl2UsernamePasswordTable = new SQLiteCommand(insertIntoUsernamePasswordString);

                    insertIntoTbl1Table.Connection = DbConnection;
                    insertIntoTbl2UsernamePasswordTable.Connection = DbConnection;

                    insertIntoTbl1Table.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tbl1EnvironmentType", ComboBoxTbl1EnvironmentType.Text);
                    insertIntoTbl1Table.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tbl1URL", TextBoxTbl1Url.Text);
                    insertIntoTbl1Table.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tbl1Server", TextBoxTbl1ServerName.Text);
                    insertIntoTbl1Table.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tbl1ModifiedDate", ModifiedDateTime);

                    insertIntoTbl2UsernamePasswordTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tbl2Username", TextBoxTbl2Username.Text);
                    insertIntoTbl2UsernamePasswordTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tbl2Password", TextBoxTbl2Password.Text);
                    insertIntoTbl2UsernamePasswordTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tbl1Server", TextBoxTbl1ServerName.Text);
                    insertIntoTbl2UsernamePasswordTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tbl1ModifiedDate", ModifiedDateTime);

                    try
                    {
                        DbConnection.Open();
                        insertIntoTbl1Table.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        insertIntoTbl2UsernamePasswordTable.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        DbConnection.Close();
                        MessageBox.Show("Successfully updated");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you query the table to check whether the conditions that you specified do satisfy for an update ?

Comment: @Nilesh No I am just updating it anyway, even if an item hasn't change. To test this, I am specifically changing all fields and the data in tbl1 updates but updates in tbl2

Comment: what I meant was `WHERE(Tbl2UsernamePassword.Deleted = 0) AND (Tbl2UsernamePassword.Tbl2UsernamePasswordsID = '" + Tbl2UsernamePasswordsID.Text + "')")` does this condition return any rows when you use a select statement? cause glancing at the code it does look correct.

Comment: @Nilesh Yes it returns rows.